# how to add fields to database using hook functions and how should i write a return function

Tags: drupal, hook

I added fields mobile no,landline no, using the below code to the form which i created with registration module. when i fill the fields along with two added fields and submit them by clicking save registration button.I cannot find the two added field in database.how can i make them appear in database.

```
function search_enhance_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

if($form_id == 'registration form') {
  $form['mobile no'] = array(
  '#type' => 'fieldset',
  '#title' => t('mobile no'),
  '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  '#weight' => 30,
);
$form['mobile no']['text'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#description' => t('This is a test to see the form_alter hook in action1.'),
);

$form['text'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#description' => t('This is a test to see the form_alter hook in action.'),
  '#title' => t('land line no'),
  '#weight' => 10,
);
}         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks are (your) functions that will be executed before/after some specific code is executed. I.e. "hook_user_login" will be called when user just logged in.

You can place hook functions in your module or in theme template file. I.e. if you module has  name "test" you should name hook function "test_user_login" so drupal can find it and execute it when needed. So, instead of "hook" you should place name of your module/theme.

Next, after adding you hook function you should clear the cache (Configuration -> Development -> Performance in admin menu).

You can use hook functions to do some your stuff when some even occurs, but some hooks are also allowing you to change some values that will be passed to code that will be executed after your hook in the process.